# Streaming Audio From Voscast Server

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, streaming, audio-streaming

I am working on an app I would like to basically be a radio style app.  I have a site set up that uses Voscast to play through content that I have set up.  Are there any good tutorials for setting up an iPhone app that you can stream from your voscast site, and pull in metadata off of what is currently playing?

Comment: Did you found a solution cause i have one? just in case u haven't btw its in the VosCast Knowledge Base

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit late, but you can do this using an html5 player by adding this to your HTML code:

```
<iframe width="150" scrolling="no" height="30" frameborder="0" src="http://cdn.voscast.com/player/player.php?host=[yourHostHere]&port=[yourPortHere]"></iframe>
```